# Csv file deletes a column when shown in IntelliJ excelReader plugin

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I'm learning to code in IntelliJ and I have a csv file that does not show up correctly in the excelReader plugin. When I view it in the excelReader plugin,  they are missing columns. My host.csv is missing its weekend_rate. I initially thought this doesn't matter because when I view it through my computer, the form is back to its original. However, my method to read the files always comes back null because it doesn't have every column to read from. Has this ever happened to anyone? If so, how do I fix it?

(All pii I'm sharing in the images was fabricated for educational purposes)

File on my computer

[image: 1]

Same file on intelliJ

[image: 2]

Comment: Seems there was similar issue in plugin: https://github.com/obiscr/ExcelReader/issues/11. Please check used version.